# Date and SQLite.jl encoding - Julia

Tags: sqlite, date, julia

I am doing some work on SQLite sandbox in Julia, and for some reason, I am not able to filter data using dates as criteria. Following is my code.

```
    using Pkg
    Pkg.add("CSV")
    Pkg.add("DataFrames")
    Pkg.add("SQLite")

    using CSV
    using DataFrames
    using SQLite

    path = "/Users/ak/Desktop/Data"

    orders = CSV.read(joinpath(path, "orders.csv"))
    println(size(orders))
    first(orders, 5)

    acme = SQLite.DB() 
    SQLite.load!(orders, acme, "orders") 

    DataFrame(SQLite.Query(acme,"""select * from orders
          where orderdate > '1997-01-01'
          """))
```

All queries with dates criteria seem to work perfectly on SQLite DB browser, but doesn't work on Julia. Could someone please advise what am I doing wrong.

Following is the example of the database

```
    OrderID | CustomersID  | EmployeeID  | Orderdate  | ShipperID 
     10248  |    90        |    5        | 1996-07-04 |  3
     10249  |    81        |    6        | 1996-07-05 |  1
```

Comment: Does your orderdate column have values that are strings in the same `YYYY-MM-DD` format you're comparing them to?

Comment: Yes sir -  same format.

Comment: Show some sample rows from your database?

Comment: Please see the example of one the table.

Comment: ... maybe some rows your statement is supposed to return?

Comment: You have not explained what does *doesn't work on Julia* mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    table_name = CSV.read(joinpath(path, "table_name.csv");types= . 
    [Int64,Int64,Int64,String,Int64])
```

I simply called the date field as a string when reading and it worked like a magic.